# Pass 1.1.3 - Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, fingerprint

When I generate apk release using proguard and using libraries necessary to Fingerprint Samsung (pass-v1.1.3.jar, sdk-v1.0.0.jar), I get the following error:

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassFingerprint$b: can't find superclass or interface com.samsung.android.fingerprint.IFingerprintClient$Stub
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassFingerprint$c: can't find superclass or interface com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintIdentifyDialog$FingerprintListener
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.b: can't find superclass or interface com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintManager$EnrollFinishListener
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassFingerprint: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintIdentifyDialog
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassFingerprint: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintIdentifyDialog$FingerprintListener
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassFingerprint: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintManager
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassFingerprint: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintManager$EnrollFinishListener
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassFingerprint: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.IFingerprintClient
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassFingerprint: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.IFingerprintClient
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassFingerprint: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.IFingerprintClient
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassFingerprint$b: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintEvent
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassFingerprint$b: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.IFingerprintClient
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassFingerprint$b: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.IFingerprintClient$Stub
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassFingerprint$b: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintEvent
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassFingerprint$b: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.IFingerprintClient$Stub
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassFingerprint$b: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintEvent
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassFingerprint$c: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintEvent
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassFingerprint$c: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintIdentifyDialog
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassFingerprint$c: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintIdentifyDialog$FingerprintListener
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassFingerprint$c: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintEvent
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassFingerprint$c: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintEvent
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassFingerprint$c: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintEvent
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.b: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintManager
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.b: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintManager$EnrollFinishListener
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.c: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintEvent
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.c: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintEvent
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.c: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintEvent
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.c: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintEvent
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.c: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintEvent
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.c: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintEvent
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.d: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintEvent
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.d: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintEvent
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.d: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintEvent
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.d: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintEvent
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.e: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintEvent
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.e: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintEvent
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.e: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintEvent
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.e: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintEvent
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.e: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintEvent
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.e: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintEvent
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.support.IFingerprintManagerProxy: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintIdentifyDialog
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.support.IFingerprintManagerProxy: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintIdentifyDialog$FingerprintListener
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.support.IFingerprintManagerProxy: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintManager
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.support.IFingerprintManagerProxy: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintManager$EnrollFinishListener
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.support.IFingerprintManagerProxy: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.IFingerprintClient
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.support.IFingerprintManagerProxy: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintIdentifyDialog$FingerprintListener
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.support.IFingerprintManagerProxy: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintManager$EnrollFinishListener
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.support.IFingerprintManagerProxy: can't find referenced class com.samsung.android.fingerprint.IFingerprintClient
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] Warning: there were 48 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2015-05-07 19:56:57 - ] at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

**What should I put in the proguard-project.txt?**
How could I fix it?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ignore warnings by adding below lines in proguard.

```
-dontwarn com.samsung.**

-keep class com.samsung.** {*;}
```